# How to estimate the memory size of a binary voxelized geometry?

Tags: memory, 3d, geometry, voxel

Say there is a 3D geometry in a box with N^3 elements or voxels.
How to estimate the memory size of the voxelized geometry given that the elements are binary (1 or 0)? Is it simply N^3 bits or is there a lower size version such that the data is compressed?

Comment: Welp, if the volume is empty all voxels are empty and can be compressed down to few bytes. If the volume is full with RNG data it can't be comressed at all and will take N^3 bits.